# How to pass on DNS servers to another interface?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, dhcp, dnsmasq

I have two ethernet interfaces, eth0, and eth1 on ubuntu 17.04.  eth0 is configured for DHCP and obtains an IP address, gateway, and DNS servers.  This is a mobile PC so these change everytime.

eth1 is a local network where I would like to provide a DHCP server with the basic features of supplying an IP (static or dynamic), gateway, search domain, and a primary and secondary DNS.  I'd like to pass on eth0's DNS servers and not some static pre-known option.  How is this accomplished?

Once I connect eth0, dnsmasq seems to be doing the resolving and I can't seem to find (a) where the two servers are stored and (b) dynamically instruct a DHCP server either isc-dhcp or dnsmasq or whatever to use those in the offers.

Much appreciated!

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you need to pass DNS servers for the second interface, because I'm pretty sure that there is only one system resolver. But you can check your DNS-servers with:

```
$ nmcli connection show <CONNECTION_NAME> | egrep "DNS|\sdomain_name_servers"
```

You can list your active connection name with:

```
$ nmcli connection show --active
```

You can set new DNS-servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 in this case) with:

```
$ sudo dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq /uk/org/thekelleys/dnsmasq uk.org.thekelleys.SetDomainServers "array:string:8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4"
```

And check if it is succeed with:

```
$ journalctl -n -b _COMM=dnsmasq
```

and

```
$ sudo kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid` && sleep .5; journalctl -n -b _COMM=dnsmasq
```

**Update:**
If you want to provide your own DHCP server which offer DNS records it's better to let your `dnmasq` instanse serve DNS queries. So let `dnsmasq` listen on your `eth0` interface:

```
$ sudo tee <<< "interface=eth0" /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/bind-eth0.conf
$ sudo systemctl reload NetworkManager
```

And set your DHCP server to offer eth0's IP address as the DNS-server.